# The spring data JPA repository.save method automatically saves all entities？

Tags: java, spring, database, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In the following code, why is user1 saved to the database?
repository.save method automatically saves all entities？

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public void test() {
        User user1 = userRepository.findById(1);
        user1.setPhone("1");

        User user2 = userRepository.findById(2);
        userRepository.save(user2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The *repository* doesn't save the entities; instead, JPA is a "magic" system where changes to persistent entities are automatically saved when the transaction commits. Repositories using other persistence technologies do require explicit save operations for each object.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it depends upon your transaction boundary, if you have an active non-readonly transaction and you are doing some modifications to managed (attached) entities, all the changes will be saved/persisted once transaction is committed.
This is fundamental principle of JPA/Hibernate.
Ideally attached entities should not be modified if changes are not required.